# Issue with deploying a React website to Firebase

Tags: firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I'm trying to host my very first website to Firebase.
I'm reading this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@devesu/host-a-react-based-website-free-of-cost-with-firebase-hosting-and-connect-with-your-own-domain-53146731807f) but there seem to be something wrong.

I'm supposed to pick -

```
( ) Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites
```

But that selection is missing in the list.

Instead I got -

```
( ) Realtime Database: Configure a security rules file for Realtime Database and (optionally) provision default instance
( ) Firestore: Configure security rules and indexes files for Firestore
( ) Functions: Configure a Cloud Functions directory and its files
( ) Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys
( ) Hosting: Set up GitHub Action deploys
( ) Storage: Configure a security rules file for Cloud Storage
( ) Emulators: Set up local emulators for Firebase products
```

So what do I do?
Which one should I choose?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for this option:

> ( ) Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys

Deploying to hosting has been expanded to (optionally) also cover GitHub actions, but you can still do the basic scenario thought it too.

Comment: Thank you so much